# How to draw line on an osm map

Tags: android

I have an OSM Map and I have got updated latitude and longitude as I am moving on the way, after every 10 seconds. I want to draw a route line on the map as the user moves away.
i.e. I want to connect all the pairs of lat-lon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Osmdroid to display your OSM map, then what you need is a **PathOverlay** to which you can add points with its addPoint() method. See my answer to this question [OSMDroid PathOverlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104581/osmdroid-pathoverlay/10109812#10109812)

You should be able to adapt your code very easily from this example.

Comment: Yeah its working... thanks Sir..., Now I am able to draw the path but I have three buttons on my map scree. Pause(to pause path recording),poi(to add pin on a specific location) and start/stop(to start or stop recording).in my onLocationChanged(), I m calling requestUpdate...() and I m giving 10 mtr length and 1 minute time for update location.But I receive lat/lon either i close the App. I also call removeUpdate...() on clicking on pause and stop both.Then why I receive lat/lon continuously. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
private Polyline polyline;
private ArrayList<GeoPoint> pathPoints;

polyline = new Polyline();
polyline.setColor(Helper.getColor(context, R.color.red));
polyline.setWidth(POLYLINE_WIDTH);
mapView.getOverlays().add(polyline);

pathPoints.add(newLatLon);
pathPoints.add(newLatLon1);
pathPoints.add(newLatLon2);
polyline.setPoints(pathPoints);
```