# How to draw path between two marker?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am using osm in my android application. And i have to show a path between two marker.I have used path overlay but line not draw.

Anyone knows how to draw line between two marker in android osm map ?

Comment: may be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874351/how-to-display-route-on-my-osm-application  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104581/osmdroid-pathoverlay/10109812#10109812  will be useful to you

Comment: thnxs for reply but this link not work for me i have tried both

Answer (score 4):

I got the solution — here is the answer:

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager();
            ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
            GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(source_lat, source_longi);               
            waypoints.add(startPoint);
            GeoPoint endPoint = new GeoPoint(desti_lat,desti_longi);
            waypoints.add(endPoint);                    
            try 
            {
                road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);
            } 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    if (road.mStatus != Road.STATUS_OK)
                    {
                          //handle error... warn the user, etc. 
                    }

                    Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road, Color.RED, 8, context);
                    map.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay);                 
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

And I am using two JAR files: `slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar` and `osmdroid-android-4.2.jar`, and `osmbonuspack` library.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: i got solution that's why i put in answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the open source route planner [GraphHopper](https://graphhopper.com/) (where I'm the author of) which works offline on Android and iOS. See [the Android documentation](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/android/index.md), which uses mapsforge and the code is [here](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/android/MainActivity.java#L523):

```
mapView = new MapView(this);
...
mapView.getLayerManager().getLayers().add(createPolyline(resp));
```

Or you can use it via online connection too, here are [JavaScript](https://github.com/graphhopper/directions-api-js-client) and [Java](https://github.com/graphhopper/directions-api-java-client) clients.

Answer (score 0):

```
 float[] arr=new float[5];

            android.location.Location.distanceBetween(latitude,longitude,(Double.parseDouble(bn.getString("lat"))),(Double.parseDouble(bn.getString("lon"))),arr);

            System.out.println("distance"+arr[0]);
            if(arr[0]>5){

            if(isNetworkAvailable()){

                if(latitude!=0){

                 findDirections( latitude, longitude,Double.parseDouble(bn.getString("lat")),Double.parseDouble( bn.getString("lon")), GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING );

                }else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sorry can't access your current location",1500).show();

            }

public void findDirections(double fromPositionDoubleLat, double fromPositionDoubleLong, double toPositionDoubleLat, double toPositionDoubleLong, String mode)
    {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_LAT, String.valueOf(fromPositionDoubleLat));
        map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_LONG, String.valueOf(fromPositionDoubleLong));
        map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DESTINATION_LAT, String.valueOf(toPositionDoubleLat));
        map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DESTINATION_LONG, String.valueOf(toPositionDoubleLong));
        map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DIRECTIONS_MODE, mode);

        GetDirectionsAsyncTask asyncTask = new GetDirectionsAsyncTask(this);
        asyncTask.execute(map); 
    }
    public void handleGetDirectionsResult(ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoints) {
        PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.RED);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoints.size() ; i++) 
        {          
            rectLine.add(directionPoints.get(i));
        }
        if (newPolyline != null)
        {
            newPolyline.remove();
        }
        newPolyline = map.addPolyline(rectLine);
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();


            latlngBounds = createLatLngBoundsObject(new LatLng(latitude, longitude),new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(bn.getString("lat")),Double.parseDouble( bn.getString("lon"))));
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latlngBounds, display.getWidth(), display.getHeight(), 150));



    }
    private LatLngBounds createLatLngBoundsObject(LatLng firstLocation, LatLng secondLocation)
    {
        if (firstLocation != null && secondLocation != null)
        {
            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();    
            builder.include(firstLocation).include(secondLocation);

            return builder.build();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: i think this is for google map not for open street map